# I created an NFT Contract through my SAFE - How do I find the created contract address?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I followed these steps to drop an NFT Contract through my Safe: https://gist.github.com/ryanio/8d605bf4d76127e9bfbe0d2f09996135

Everything worked, signed and transaction was successful - But where do I find this newly created contract address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your wallet, you should see "My Contracts" or "Deployed Contracts". Thats where you can find the addresses